# How do I install a package on OSX without recompiling everything?

Tags: ros, catkin, macosx, rosws, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed ROS Hydro on OS X Mavericks, and I'm looking to install additional packages that weren't included in the full install.

I can't simply get the binaries (they're not on homebrew) so I need to go the manual route. My plan was to do this:

```
rosrlocate info PACKAGE | rosws merge -
rosws update
mv PACKAGE src/PACKAGE
rosdep install PACKAGE
catkin_make_isolated
```

Except when I do `catkin_make_isolated`, I recompile all the source files from the installation. Do I need to create a new rosws and install packages there? Is my ros_catkin_ws from the OS X install now more-or-less equivalent to /opt/ros/hydro, in that I shouldn't touch it but I should keep it on my ROS paths?

I wanted to get an idea of the standards before mucking about!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118301/how-do-i-install-a-package-on-osx-without-recompiling-everything?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended workflow is to build another workspace on top of the one in `~/ros_catkin_ws`. Also for catkin, you should use `rosinstall_generator` and `wstool`. So you would do something like this:

```
mkdir ~/my_ws
cd ~/my_ws
wstool init src
source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
rosinstall_generator PACKAGE --deps --exclude RPP | wstool merge -t src -
wstool update -t src
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
catkin_make_isolated --install
source ~/my_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
```

`wstool` is the ROS agnostic replacement for `rosws`, and has most of the same functions, but you normally have to specify the target folder to act on, hence the `-t src` in the `merge` command. The `wstool update -t src` command will cause the packages you just added to be fetched.

`rosinstall_generator` is pretty new, and currently can only operate on released packages, but should be able to get packages from source in the future. The `--deps --exclude RPP` options to `rosinstall_generator` means get me that `PACKAGE` and its dependencies, recursively, excluding dependencies in my `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. This is the best way to create an "extension" on top of your existing workspace of ROS packages.

The `--from-paths src` and `--ignore-src` arguments to `rosdep` indicate that it should install all of the dependencies of packages found in the folder `src` and that it should not try to install packages found of the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` respectively.

Hopefully that helps, we are working on improving these tools and getting tutorials setup to give them more visibility to them.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-01-15**:
Thanks for the awesome response! Sadly, it didn't entirely work as it never grabbed the source files. I merged your commands with the OS X install to come up with the answer below. This works when initializing the workspace – I'm not sure why `wstool merge -t src -` didn't grab the source files.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-15**:
Oops, forgot to call `wstool update`.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-01-15**:
Just because I'm going to use this post as a reference in the future, would you mind editing your codeblock to include the `--install` flag to catkin_make as well as a `source install_isolated/setup.bash` line? Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-15**:
Sure, though the `--install` is optional.